# Rails Tutorial: Problems issuing a DELETE request for an admin user (Chapter 9, Exercise 9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I am doing Michael Hartl’s fantastic [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org) and I’ve seen many people having problems with [Chapter 9, Exercise 9](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-updating_deleting_exercises). I’ve also had my fair share of problems but I didn’t see anywhere else my exact problem (or the solution). So here it is for reference and I hope it helps others. My environment is Ruby 2.1.1, Rails 4.1.4, RSpec 3.0.0 and Capybara 2.4.1. This is different from the environment described in the book, but using the latest tools and versions was part of the fun.

The problem is designing a test and modifying the `UsersController#destroy` action to prevent admin users from deleting themselves. As the “delete” link in the Users page is hidden for each user, even those with `admin: true`, the way to go is to issue a `DELETE` request to `users_path(user)`.

```ruby
describe 'Admin cannot delete himself/herself' do
  let(:admin_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
  before { log_in admin_user }
  specify { expect { delete user_path(admin_user) }.not_to change(User, :count) }  
end
```

Running this test, however, passes:

```
$ rspec -e "cannot delete himself"
Run options: include {:full_description=>/cannot\ delete\ himself/}
.

Finished in 1.59 seconds (files took 0.98179 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Something’s fishy. Here’s the output from `log/test.log`:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('person_1@example.com') LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("admin", "created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "remember_token", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["admin", "t"], ["created_at", "2014-08-13 13:56:11.310082"], ["email", "person_1@example.com"], ["name", "Person 1"], ["password_digest", "$2a$04$.ScHVB84mm4/4G12Vcpudu/k741nyrXM4vLtZa7XgtecNB6uOHNPy"], ["remember_token", "c527083d0ba4581ed92f258eede7d1377dcf7d5b"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-13 13:56:11.310082"]]
   (0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-13 15:56:11 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_internet_explorer_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1456ms (Views: 1450.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-13 15:56:12 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "email"=>"person_1@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'person_1@example.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "remember_token" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 362  [["remember_token", "3df781e414c64f2f72cf1e08594f92595922329a"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-13 13:56:12.870234"]]
   (0.0ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Redirected to http://www.example.com/users/362
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
Started GET "/users/362" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-13 15:56:12 +0200
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"362"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 362]]
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_internet_explorer_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '3df781e414c64f2f72cf1e08594f92595922329a' LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
Started DELETE "/users/362" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-13 15:56:12 +0200
Processing by UsersController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"362"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://www.example.com/login
Filter chain halted as :logged_in_user rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

The test passes because when trying to delete a user, the filter

```
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

kicks in, as suggested by this line from the log:

```
Redirected to http://www.example.com/login
Filter chain halted as :logged_in_user rendered or redirected
```

For some reason the user isn’t logged in and, when he/she arrives at a protected page, is redirected to the log in page. You can actually see that no users are being deleted by adding a `logger.warn "<message>"` in `UsersController#destroy` or even adding `puts User.count` after the `expect` line inside the `specify` block.

Why isn’t the `:admin_user` logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, in short, is that Capybara’s mock session is different from RSpec’s. The log in is done with Capybara, whereas the `DELETE` request is sent directly from RSpec, and the `remember_token` stored in the database doesn’t match when RSpec tries to delete the admin user.

To do a pure Capybara sequence of actions we can use the Rails console with [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/13k/3086739) (omitting long outputs):

```
$ rails c -e test
Loading test environment (Rails 4.1.4)
2.1.1 :001 > User.create(name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.net', password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar', admin: true)
...
2.1.1 :002 > Capybara.app = app.instance_variable_get("@app"); nil
 => nil 
2.1.1 :003 > cap = Object.new.instance_eval { extend Capybara::DSL; self }
 => #<Object:0x00000004a5b758> 
2.1.1 :004 > cap.visit app.login_path
...
2.1.1 :005 > cap.fill_in 'Email', with: 'foo@bar.net'
 => "foo@bar.net" 
2.1.1 :006 > cap.fill_in 'Password', with: 'foobar'
 => "foobar" 
2.1.1 :007 > cap.click_button 'Log in'
...
2.1.1 :009 > admin_user = User.find_by(email: 'foo@bar.net')
...
2.1.1 :010 > cap.page.driver.delete app.user_path(admin_user)
...
2.1.1 :011 > User.count
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
 => 0 
2.1.1 :013 >
```

Also, looking at the original logs in the question we can see that the `remember_token` after logging in is different than the one set in the `DELETE` request.

In summary, the correct way to write the test is with `no_capybara: true`:

```
describe 'Admin cannot delete himself/herself' do
  let(:admin_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
  before { log_in admin_user, no_capybara: true }
  specify { expect { delete user_path(admin_user) }.not_to change(User, :count) }  
end
```

Which yields the following:

```
$ rspec -e "cannot delete himself"
Run options: include {:full_description=>/cannot\ delete\ himself/}
F

Failures:

  1) Admin cannot delete himself with a DELETE request should not change #count
     Failure/Error: specify { expect { delete user_path(admin_user) }.not_to change(User, :count) }
       expected #count not to have changed, but did change from 1 to 0
     # ./spec/requests/admin_autodelete_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.04263 seconds (files took 0.99411 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/admin_autodelete_spec.rb:7 # Admin cannot delete himself with a DELETE request should not change #count
```

And now you can proceed to solve the exercise. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The root issue is that you've ended up some using the capybara methods for logging in (visit, click) and so on but the rails integration test methods for the delete request.

Since these two are completely separate, the cookies set by the logging in process aren't used by your delete request. Note that in the page you link to, they do

```
before { sign_in non_admin, no_capybara: true }
```

This causes the `sign_in` helper to set cookies directly instead of going to the page, filling in the form etc.

Comment: Yes, I wrote my own answer with a more in-depth explanation and the way I found out about the problem.